# Dynamic lambda select expression

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, lambda, expression-trees

I have a lambda expression tree issue that I can’t figure out. I am trying to make a dynamic linq Select statement.

I have a dynamic repository created here:

```
private static dynamic GetRepository(Type type)
{
    dynamic repository = typeof(IFactory).GetMethod("Create").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(IRepository<>).MakeGenericType(type)).Invoke(ObjectFactory.Instance, new object[] { });
    return repository;
}
```

With this I need to call this only I don’t know x and SomeProperty at compile time. I have PropertyInfo propertyInfo with SomeProperty name and Type objectType with x type. 
It fails at Goal 1 with this exception:

> System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException at GetMethod(string name)

The code:

```
private SomeObject CreateSomeObject (PropertyInfo propertyInfo, Type objectType)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(objectType, "x");
    MemberExpression expression = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, propertyInfo.Name);

    //Goal 1: var selectExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<objectType, object>>(expression, param);
    var selectExpression = typeof(Expression).GetMethod("Lambda").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Func<,>)
    .MakeGenericType(objectType, typeof(object)))
    .Invoke((object)null, new object[] { expression, param });

    // Goal 2: List<object> list = GetRepository(objectType).FindAllQuery().Select(x => x.SomeProperty).ToList();
    List<object> list = GetRepository(objectType).FindAll().Select(selectExpression);
}
```

How to solve this?

**Update 1:**

I have changed the way to select Lambda method, the way to pack 'param' parameter and I have added a object Converter to 'expression'.

```
private SomeObject CreateSomeObject (PropertyInfo propertyInfo, Type objectType)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(objectType, "x");
    Expression expression = Expression.Convert(Expression.PropertyOrField(param, propertyInfo.Name), typeof(object));

    //Goal 1: var selectExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<objectType, object>>(expression, param);
    var selectExpression = typeof(Expression).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "Lambda" && m.IsGenericMethod)
    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Func<,>)
    .MakeGenericType(objectType, typeof(object)))
    .Invoke((object)null, new object[] { expression, new [] { param }});

    // Goal 2: List<object> list = GetRepository(objectType).FindAllQuery().Select(x => x.SomeProperty).ToList();
    List<object> list = GetRepository(objectType).FindAll().Select(selectExpression);
}
```

But know I get this exception at Goal 2(Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException):

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List ' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Select'

This is partly right because it is defined in System.Linq and it is an extension method.  How do I get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that throws the exception is

```csharp
typeof(Expression).GetMethod("Lambda")
```

because there are 18 methods called `Lambda` defined on the `Expression` type (thus the `AmbiguousMatchException`).

`GetMethod(string methodName)` is appropriate when there are no overloads. In this case I would use `GetMethods()` and then filter out the one I need.

In your case, the right overload is

```csharp
Expression.Lambda<TDelegate>(Expression body, params ParameterExpression[] parameters)
```

You could write a function that validates the right overload by checking the number of parameters and their type, but I found an easier alternative: filter the method by the `.ToString()` representation, which in our case is:

```csharp
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[TDelegate] Lambda[TDelegate](System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression[])
```

There's also a problem with the way you pass the parameters (`new object[] { expression, param }`). The second parameter is not of type `ParameterExpression`, but `ParameterExpression[]` (array), therefore you should pass `new[]{param}` instead of just `param`. When calling it in regular code it works like that because it's defined as `params ParameterExpression[]`.

In conclusion, the following code should work in your case:

```csharp
const string methodSignature = 
    "System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[TDelegate] Lambda[TDelegate]" +
    "(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression[])";

var lambdaMethod = typeof (Expression).GetMethods()
    .Single(mi => mi.ToString() == methodSignature);

var funcType = typeof (Func<,>).MakeGenericType(objectType, typeof (object));

var genericLambda = lambdaMethod.MakeGenericMethod(funcType);

var selectExpression = genericLambda.Invoke(null, new object[] { expression, new[] { param } });
```

Comment: Actually [there are 18 methods called `Lambda` on `Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.lambda.aspx) and 6 of them are generic. So, your code will return one of the generic ones, but I think it most likely won't be the right one.

Comment: Thanks.. Now I get: A object of the type 'System.Linq.Expressions.TypedParameterExpression' can’t be converted to the type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression[]'. At the Invoke
method.

Comment: Please see the update in the original post - any solution on that exception?

Comment: @MortenHolmgaard the `.First(m => m.Name == "Lambda" && m.IsGenericMethod)` condition is wrong, as @svick pointed out above. Please see if the update to my answer solves your problem.

Comment: I have tried your new solution, and just as in my 'Update 1' this seams to work but I den get an exception when calling 'Select'.. I get: 'System.Collections.Generic.List ' does not contain a definition for 'Select'.. Se my update..

Comment: @MortenHolmgaard That's because extension methods don't work on `dynamic`. But I'm not sure how exactly to fix that in your case.

Comment: @MortenHolmgaard if you do `.Select(x => x.SomeProperty)`) instead of `.Select(selectExpression)`, does that work?

Comment: No I can't because of dynamic.. I have tried som invoke of the extension method with `var queryList = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "Select").MakeGenericMethod(objectType, typeof(object)).Invoke(null, new[] { _repository.FindAll(), selectExpression });` but it throws ArgumentException.. I have just for now solved it the old way, but I am still interested in a solution: `IList<double> allValues = new List<double>();
   foreach (var obj in _repository.FindAll())
    allValues.Add((double)ReflectionHelper.GetProperty<object>(propertyInfo.Name, obj));`